# Preventing user from scrolling a div on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a div that can move up and down, but it's scrolling is not controlled directly by the user. I've implemented the following code to prevent the user from scrolling this div.

```
$('.teamheading').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function (e) { return false; });
```

This works great on desktop. It doesn't work on mobile though. Do you know what the mobile equivalent of this would be?

Thanks!

Comment: Try the `scroll` event. Also, check the version of jQuery you're using as `bind()` was deprecated *a long* time ago and shouldn't be used. Use `on()` instead

Comment: Thanks Rory! Impressive profile! I'm on jquery 3.4.1. Doesn't seem too old from what I can see.

Comment: 3.4.1 is fine, although 3.6.0 is the very latest, but you really should move to `on()` as `bind()` will most likely be removed from the next full version update.

Answer (score -1):

You can listen for the event

```
[div].addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  // your code here
});
```

Comment: what if I want nothing to run on that scroll event, including preventing the div from scrolling?

Comment: one trick is to, get the scroll values and offset the div so it looks not scrolled at all.